# How to prune weights less than a threshold in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, pruning

*How to prune weights of a CNN (convolution neural network) model which is less than a **threshold value** (let's consider prune all weights which are <= 1).*

How we can achieve that for a weight file saved in .pth format in pytorch?

Answer (score 18):

PyTorch since `1.4.0` provides model pruning out of the box, [see official tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/pruning_tutorial.html).

As there is no `threshold` method to prune in PyTorch currently, you have to implement it yourself, though it's kinda easy once you get the overall idea.

### Threshold Pruning method

Below is a code performing pruning:

```
from torch.nn.utils import prune


class ThresholdPruning(prune.BasePruningMethod):
    PRUNING_TYPE = "unstructured"

    def __init__(self, threshold):
        self.threshold = threshold

    def compute_mask(self, tensor, default_mask):
        return torch.abs(tensor) > self.threshold
```

Explanation:

- `PRUNING_TYPE` can be one of `global`, `structured`, `unstructured`. `global` acts across whole module (e.g. remove `20%` of weight with smallest value), `structured` acts on whole channels/modules. We need `unstructured` as we would like to modify each connection in specific parameter tensor (say `weight` or `bias`)
- `__init__` - pass here whatever you want or need to make it work, normal stuff
- `compute_mask` - mask to be used to prune specific tensor. In our case all parameters below threshold should be zero. I did it with absolute value as it makes more sense. `default_mask` is not needed here, but is left as named parameter as that's what API requires atm.

Moreover, inheriting from `prune.BasePruningMethod` defines methods to apply the mask to each parameter, make pruning permanent etc. See [base class docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.utils.prune.BasePruningMethod) for more info.

### Example module

Nothing too fancy, you can put anything you want here:

```
class MyModule(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.first = torch.nn.Linear(50, 30)
        self.second = torch.nn.Linear(30, 10)

    def forward(self, inputs):
        return self.second(torch.relu(self.first(inputs)))


module = MyModule()
```

You can also load your module via `module = torch.load('checkpoint.pth')`
if you need, it doesn't matter.

### Prune module's parameters

We should define which parameter of our module (and whether it's `weight` or `bias`) should be pruned, like this:

```
parameters_to_prune = ((module.first, "weight"), (module.second, "weight"))
```

Now, we can apply `global`ly our `unstructured` pruning to all defined `parameters` (`threshold` is passed as `kwarg` to `__init__` of `ThresholdPruning`):

```
prune.global_unstructured(
    parameters_to_prune, pruning_method=ThresholdPruning, threshold=0.1
)
```

### Results

#### `weight` attribute

To see the effect, check weights of `first` submodule simply with:

```
print(module.first.weight)
```

It is a weight with our pruning technique applied, but **please notice it's not a `torch.nn.Parameter` anymore!** Now it is simply an attribute of our model, hence **it won't take part in training or evaluation** currently.

#### `weight_mask`

We can check created mask via `module.first.weight_mask` to see everything is done correctly (it will be binary in this case).

#### `weight_orig`

Applying pruning creates a new `torch.nn.Parameter` with original weights named `name + _orig`, in this case `weight_orig`, let's see:

```
print(module.first.weight_orig)
```

**This parameter will be used during training and evaluation currently!**. After applying `pruning` via methods described above there are `forward_pre_hooks` added which "switch" original `weight` to `weight_orig`.

Due to such approach you can define and apply your pruning at any part of `training` or `inference` without "destroying" original weights.

### Applying pruning permanently

If you wish to apply pruning permanently simply issue:

```
prune.remove(module.first, "weight")
```

And now our `module.first.weight` is once again parameter with entries appropriately pruned, `module.first.weight_mask` is removed and so is `module.first.weight_orig`. **It's what you are probably after**.

You can iterate over `children` to make it permanent:

```
for child in module.children():
    prune.remove(child, "weight")
```

You could define `parameters_to_prune` using the same logic:

```
parameters_to_prune = [(child, "weight") for child in module.children()]
```

Or if you want only `convolution` layers to be pruned (or anything else really):

```
parameters_to_prune = [
    (child, "weight")
    for child in module.children()
    if isinstance(child, torch.nn.Conv2d)
]
```

### Advantages

- uses "PyTorch way of pruning" so it's easier to communicate your intent to other programmers
- define pruning on a per-tensor basis, single responsibility instead of going through everything
- confine to predefined ways
- pruning **is not permanent** hence you can recover from it if needed. Module can be saved with pruning masks and original weights so it leaves you some space to revert eventual mistake (e.g. `threshold` was too high and now all your weights are zero rendering results meaningless)
- works with original weights during `forward` calls unless you want to finally change to pruned version (simple call to `remove`)

### Disadvantages

- IMO pruning API could be clearer
- You can do it shorter (as provided by [`Shai`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61629589/10886420))
- might be confusing for those who do not know such thing is "defined" by PyTorch (still there are tutorials and docs so I don't think it's a major problem)

Comment: In case you are interested in *structured pruning* (pruning of neurons instead of single weights) you can consider external libraries such as [TorchPruner](https://github.com/marcoancona/TorchPruner/)

Comment: @MarcoAncona starred, but next time when you are showing your relevant work (like your library) in answer/comment, please make a disclaimer you are an author, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can work directly on the values saved in the `state_dict`:

```py
sd = torch.load('saved_weights.pth')  # load the state dicd
for k in sd.keys():
  if not 'weight' in k:
    continue  # skip biases and other saved parameters
  w = sd[k]
  sd[k] = w * (w > thr)  # set to zero weights smaller than thr 
torch.save(sd, 'pruned_weights.pth')
```

Comment: Using this, while back propagating, the sparsity might not be maintained because you are not computing a mask for bitwise element-wise multiplication to maintain sparsity.